# Android fragment disappears

Tags: android, android-fragments

Context:

I added an image to explain the problem visually:
[click for image explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjgnA.png)

I have an Activity as well as 5 fragments(Subject, Courses, AddCourse and Assignments)

On the Activity I use a bottom navigation bar to switch between Courses fragment and Assignments fragment.

When I start the Activity, the Courses fragment is initially on the screen.
The Courses fragment is meant to be a list of subjects but initially there are 0 subjects on this fragment and a button Add Subject. When I click on the Add Subject button, the AddCourse fragment replaces Courses. Once I enter the subject information inside the AddCourse fragment and click confirm, it creates a new Subject fragment and fills it with all the information filled in the AddCourse fragment, then sends it to the Activity through an interface.
Then, the Activity sends the subject to the Courses fragment and puts it on the screen(the Courses fragment with the subject inside of it). This works great. However, when I switch to the Assignments fragment and come back to the Courses fragment, the subject is gone.

here is some code:

**Activity.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder;

import com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar;
import com.roughike.bottombar.OnTabSelectListener;

public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddCourseInterface {

    private Subject subject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
                swapPage(tabId);
            }
        });

    }

    public void swapPage(@IdRes int tabId)
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        if (tabId == R.id.tab_courses) {
            //if (subject != null) subject.print();
            ft.replace(R.id.content, Courses.newInstance(subject));
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
        else if (tabId == R.id.tab_assignments) {
            ft.replace(R.id.content, Assignments.newInstance());
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
        else if (tabId == R.id.tab_agenda) {
            ft.replace(R.id.content, Agenda.newInstance());
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
        else if (tabId == R.id.tab_exams) {
            ft.replace(R.id.content, Exams.newInstance());
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
        else if (tabId == R.id.tab_grades) {
            ft.replace(R.id.content, Grades.newInstance());
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void sendCourse(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, Courses.newInstance(subject));
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**AddCourse.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddCourse extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View inflatedView;
    private AddCourseInterface comm;

    private TextView nameText;
    private TextView nameGivenText;
    private TextView codeText;
    private TextView professorText;

    private CheckBox additionalCheck;
    private LinearLayout additionalInfo;
    private CheckBox monCheck;
    private LinearLayout monInfo;
    private TextView monLoc;
    private TextView monSTime;
    private TextView monETime;
    private CheckBox tueCheck;
    private LinearLayout tueInfo;
    private TextView tueLoc;
    private TextView tueSTime;
    private TextView tueETime;
    private CheckBox wedCheck;
    private LinearLayout wedInfo;
    private TextView wedLoc;
    private TextView wedSTime;
    private TextView wedETime;
    private CheckBox thuCheck;
    private LinearLayout thuInfo;
    private TextView thuLoc;
    private TextView thuSTime;
    private TextView thuETime;
    private CheckBox friCheck;
    private LinearLayout friInfo;
    private TextView friLoc;
    private TextView friSTime;
    private TextView friETime;

    private RadioButton mon_lec;
    private RadioButton mon_sem;
    private RadioButton mon_lab;

    private RadioButton tue_lec;
    private RadioButton tue_sem;
    private RadioButton tue_lab;

    private RadioButton wed_lec;
    private RadioButton wed_sem;
    private RadioButton wed_lab;

    private RadioButton thu_lec;
    private RadioButton thu_sem;
    private RadioButton thu_lab;

    private RadioButton fri_lec;
    private RadioButton fri_sem;
    private RadioButton fri_lab;

    private Button confirm;

    private String name = "Subject Name";
    private String givenName = "Short Name";
    private String code = "Course Code";
    private String professor = "Professor";

    private ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();;
    private ArrayList<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> stimes = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> etimes = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();

    public AddCourse() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static AddCourse newInstance() {

        return new AddCourse();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_course, container, false);

        nameText = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.subject_name);
        nameGivenText = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.short_name);
        codeText = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.course_code);
        professorText = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.professor);

        additionalCheck = (CheckBox) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.check_additional);
        additionalCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

        additionalInfo = (LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.additional_info);

        monCheck = (CheckBox) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.check_mon);
        monCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

        tueCheck = (CheckBox) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.check_tue);
        tueCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

        wedCheck = (CheckBox) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.check_wed);
        wedCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

        thuCheck = (CheckBox) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.check_thu);
        thuCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

        friCheck = (CheckBox) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.check_fri);
        friCheck.setOnClickListener(this);

        monInfo = (LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.monday_info);
        tueInfo = (LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tuesday_info);
        wedInfo = (LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.wednesday_info);
        thuInfo = (LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.thursday_info);
        friInfo = (LinearLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.friday_info);

        monLoc = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.monday_location);
        monSTime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.monday_stime);
        monETime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.monday_etime);

        tueLoc = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tuesday_location);
        tueSTime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tuesday_stime);
        tueETime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tuesday_etime);

        wedLoc = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.wednesday_location);
        wedSTime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.wednesday_stime);
        wedETime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.wednesday_etime);

        thuLoc = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.thursday_location);
        thuSTime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.thursday_stime);
        thuETime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.thursday_etime);

        friLoc = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.friday_location);
        friSTime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.friday_stime);
        friETime = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.friday_etime);

        mon_lec = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mon_lec);
        mon_sem = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mon_sem);
        mon_lab = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mon_lab);

        tue_lec = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tue_lec);
        tue_sem = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tue_sem);
        tue_lab = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tue_lab);

        wed_lec = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.wed_lec);
        wed_sem = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.wed_sem);
        wed_lab = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.wed_lab);

        thu_lec = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.thu_lec);
        thu_sem = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.thu_sem);
        thu_lab = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.thu_lab);

        fri_lec = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.fri_lec);
        fri_sem = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.fri_sem);
        fri_lab = (RadioButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.fri_lab);

        mon_lec.setOnClickListener(this);
        mon_sem.setOnClickListener(this);
        mon_lab.setOnClickListener(this);

        tue_lec.setOnClickListener(this);
        tue_sem.setOnClickListener(this);
        tue_lab.setOnClickListener(this);

        wed_lec.setOnClickListener(this);
        wed_sem.setOnClickListener(this);
        wed_lab.setOnClickListener(this);

        thu_lec.setOnClickListener(this);
        thu_sem.setOnClickListener(this);
        thu_lab.setOnClickListener(this);

        fri_lec.setOnClickListener(this);
        fri_sem.setOnClickListener(this);
        fri_lab.setOnClickListener(this);

        confirm = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.button_confirm_subject);
        confirm.setOnClickListener(this);

        return inflatedView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == additionalCheck)
        {
            if (additionalCheck.isChecked())
            {
                System.out.println("ADDITIONAL INFO ENABLED <---------------------");
                additionalInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("ADDITIONAL INFO DISABLED <---------------------");
                additionalInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        else if (v == monCheck)
        {
            if (monCheck.isChecked())
            {
                System.out.println("MONDAY WAS CHECKED <---------------------");
                monInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("MONDAY WAS UNCHECKED <---------------------");
                monInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        else if (v == tueCheck)
        {
            if (tueCheck.isChecked())
            {
                System.out.println("tueDAY WAS CHECKED <---------------------");
                tueInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("tueDAY WAS UNCHECKED <---------------------");
                tueInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        else if (v == wedCheck)
        {
            if (wedCheck.isChecked())
            {
                System.out.println("wedDAY WAS CHECKED <---------------------");
                wedInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("wedDAY WAS UNCHECKED <---------------------");
                wedInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        else if (v == thuCheck)
        {
            if (thuCheck.isChecked())
            {
                System.out.println("thuDAY WAS CHECKED <---------------------");
                thuInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("thuDAY WAS UNCHECKED <---------------------");
                thuInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        else if (v == friCheck)
        {
            if (friCheck.isChecked())
            {
                System.out.println("friDAY WAS CHECKED <---------------------");
                friInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("friDAY WAS UNCHECKED <---------------------");
                friInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        else if (v == mon_lec) {
            mon_lec.setChecked(true);
            mon_sem.setChecked(false);
            mon_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == mon_sem) {
            mon_lec.setChecked(false);
            mon_sem.setChecked(true);
            mon_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == mon_lab) {
            mon_lec.setChecked(false);
            mon_sem.setChecked(false);
            mon_lab.setChecked(true);
        }

        else if (v == tue_lec) {
            tue_lec.setChecked(true);
            tue_sem.setChecked(false);
            tue_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == tue_sem) {
            tue_lec.setChecked(false);
            tue_sem.setChecked(true);
            tue_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == tue_lab) {
            tue_lec.setChecked(false);
            tue_sem.setChecked(false);
            tue_lab.setChecked(true);
        }

        else if (v == wed_lec) {
            wed_lec.setChecked(true);
            wed_sem.setChecked(false);
            wed_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == wed_sem) {
            wed_lec.setChecked(false);
            wed_sem.setChecked(true);
            wed_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == wed_lab) {
            wed_lec.setChecked(false);
            wed_sem.setChecked(false);
            wed_lab.setChecked(true);
        }

        else if (v == thu_lec) {
            thu_lec.setChecked(true);
            thu_sem.setChecked(false);
            thu_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == thu_sem) {
            thu_lec.setChecked(false);
            thu_sem.setChecked(true);
            thu_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == thu_lab) {
            thu_lec.setChecked(false);
            thu_sem.setChecked(false);
            thu_lab.setChecked(true);
        }

        else if (v == fri_lec) {
            fri_lec.setChecked(true);
            fri_sem.setChecked(false);
            fri_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == fri_sem) {
            fri_lec.setChecked(false);
            fri_sem.setChecked(true);
            fri_lab.setChecked(false);
        }

        else if (v == fri_lab) {
            fri_lec.setChecked(false);
            fri_sem.setChecked(false);
            fri_lab.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if (v == confirm)
        {

            name = nameText.getText().toString();
            givenName = nameGivenText.getText().toString();
            code = codeText.getText().toString();
            professor = professorText.getText().toString();

            if (monCheck.isChecked())
            {
                days.add("monday");
                locations.add(monLoc.getText().toString());
                stimes.add(monSTime.getText().toString());
                etimes.add(monETime.getText().toString());
                if (mon_lec.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lec");
                }
                else if (mon_sem.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("sem");
                }
                else if (mon_lab.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lab");
                }
            }
            if (tueCheck.isChecked())
            {
                days.add("tuesday");
                locations.add(tueLoc.getText().toString());
                stimes.add(tueSTime.getText().toString());
                etimes.add(tueETime.getText().toString());
                if (tue_lec.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lec");
                }
                else if (tue_sem.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("sem");
                }
                else if (tue_lab.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lab");
                }
            }
            if (wedCheck.isChecked())
            {
                days.add("wednesday");
                locations.add(wedLoc.getText().toString());
                stimes.add(wedSTime.getText().toString());
                etimes.add(wedETime.getText().toString());
                if (wed_lec.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lec");
                }
                else if (wed_sem.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("sem");
                }
                else if (wed_lab.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lab");
                }
            }
            if (thuCheck.isChecked())
            {
                days.add("thursday");
                locations.add(thuLoc.getText().toString());
                stimes.add(thuSTime.getText().toString());
                etimes.add(thuETime.getText().toString());
                if (thu_lec.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lec");
                }
                else if (thu_sem.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("sem");
                }
                else if (thu_lab.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lab");
                }
            }
            if (friCheck.isChecked())
            {
                days.add("friday");
                locations.add(friLoc.getText().toString());
                stimes.add(friSTime.getText().toString());
                etimes.add(friETime.getText().toString());
                if (fri_lec.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lec");
                }
                else if (fri_sem.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("sem");
                }
                else if (fri_lab.isChecked()) {
                    types.add("lab");
                }
            }

            /*
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(givenName);
            System.out.println(code);
            System.out.println(professor);

            System.out.println(days);
            System.out.println(locations);
            System.out.println(stimes);
            System.out.println(etimes);
            System.out.println(types);
            */

            Subject subject = Subject.newInstance(name, givenName, code, professor, days, locations, stimes, etimes, types);
            comm = (AddCourseInterface) getActivity();
            comm.sendCourse(subject);
        }

    }
}
```

**Courses.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Courses extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    //private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "arg1";

    private String title;
    private TextView titleView;
    private ArrayList<Subject> subjects;
    private Subject subject;
    private View inflatedView;
    private Button addSubject;

    public Courses() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Courses newInstance(Subject s) {
        Courses courses = new Courses();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("sub1", s);
        courses.setArguments(bundle);

        return courses;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        subjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_courses, container, false);

        titleView = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.courses_title);

        addSubject = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.add_subject);
        addSubject.setOnClickListener(this);

        subject = (Subject) getArguments().getSerializable("sub1");

        if (subject != null) addSubject(subject);

        return inflatedView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void changeText(String t)
    {
        titleView.setText(t);
    }

    public void addSubject(Subject s)
    {
        subjects.add(s);
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.sub1, s);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
        System.out.println("SUBJECT ADDED TO COURSES < ------------------------");
        //subject.print();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("BUTTON CLICKED < -----------------------------------");
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, AddCourse.newInstance());
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

as you can see once I click CONFIRM in AddCourse the subject fragment appears correctly inside the Courses fragment, but once I go to Assignments and come back, the subject is gone even though I am creating the new instance of Courses using the same subject(reference saved in my activity). any ideas?

I added an image to explain the problem visually:
[click for image explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjgnA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Course fragment gets recreated that's why data is lost, you should save date to sqlite or sharedpreference and read data from there instead of passing data to activity

Comment: since I am recreating it passing the same subject to it everytime shouldn't it be the same every time? as you can see in Courses.java I have 2 prints to check if the proper subject fragment gets added: System.out.println("SUBJECT ADDED TO COURSES < ------------------------");
        subject.print(); and it seems like it is. which is why I don't understand why it isn't showing up

Comment: every time I click on the courses tab the courses fragment gets recreated using a passed subject from the activity. If every time I recreate it I pass the same subject shouldn't it always be the same?